# Не срабатывает PIE.htc

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять, почему у меня не срабатывает файл PIE.htc, подключенный для скругления углов в ие.
в стилях прописано

```
#SubPageBanner .bannerButton {
    border-radius:5px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

файлы main.css и PIE.htc находятся в одной и той же папке. В папку со стилями из распакованного архива я переношу только PIE.htc. 
Углы в ие не скругляются. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: не могу больше кооментировать в ответе. но у меня по ссылке http://kentico.corepartners.ru/App_Themes/Production/css/main.css и http://kentico.corepartners.ru/App_Themes/Production/css/PIE.htc файлы стилей и PIE.htc открываются, то есть дело не в путях. вот тут есть похожее обсуждение http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums.aspx?forumid=45&threadid=20983, но не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

в файле .htaceess вполне может быть надо поставить 
AddType text/x-component .htc

и как вариант пользовать надо:
behavior: url(PIE.php);

Comment: нет, в PIE есть 2 файла один исполняемый который сам посылает заголовок с расширением php второй просто js и имеет расширение htc. Вообще попробуйте прописать полный путь от корня сайта к PIE если это поможет то следсвенно что-то не так с объявлениями, ели нет пробуйте добавлять тип файл через AddType.

Comment: с полным путем тож не сработало

Comment: а если это сайт на Kentico, там будет .htaccess ?

Comment: нет, не будет там по другому настраивается

Comment: а как по-другому? а то я что-то не знаю, как это даже загуглить

Comment: используй PIE.php соответственно без запущенного сервера работать не будет.

Comment: *используй PIE.php соответственно без запущенного сервера работать не будет.*
что-то я не совсем понимаю?

Comment: поможет вам или нет не знаю но по ссылке говорят, что надо правильно просто путь указать: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052592/referring-htc-file-from-css-in-asp-net